# JDBC driver for Microsoft SQL server connectivity with Active Directory - Integrated authentication method using Jmeter

Tags: sql-server, authentication, jdbc, jmeter

I need to make JDBC connection using Jmeter to Microsoft SQL server which uses Active Directory - Integrated authentication method to connect to DB. Below are the setting I have done in Jmeter.
[image]
When I ran the Jmeter it shows the below exception

**java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.**

Kindly let me know is there any setting needs to be modified to overcome this issue.

Comment: Add more details about the driver you are using.and show more of your DB configuration

Answer (score 1):

1. Download [Microsoft JDBC Driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55539)
2. Copy `mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar` to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
3. Copy `sqljdbc_auth.dll` from `auth\x64` folder to [java.library.path](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadlibrary-windows.asp) or specify `java.library.path` property to point to this file location using either `-D` command-line argument or via *system.properties* file
4. Restart JMeter to pick the files up
5. Add `integratedSecurity=true` line to your JDBC URL

More information: [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter)